# How to implement mapping of objects with properties of generic Queue type via AutoMapper

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, mapping, automapper

I'd like to know whether there is a correct approach to map objects containing properties of `Queue<T>` type. 

Mapping works for `Queue<int> Log` properties in both classes.
But for `Queue<PositionDto> PositionLog` in class `TargetDto` the number of items is always 0 after the mapping.

Here is a simplified code to demonstrate that:

```
class Program
{
    public class Target
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public Queue<int> Log { get; set; }

        public Queue<Position> PositionLog { get; set; }
    }

    public class TargetDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public Queue<int> Log { get; set; }

        public Queue<PositionDto> PositionLog { get; set; }
    }

    public class Position{ }

    public class PositionDto{ }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<Target, TargetDto>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.PositionLog, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.PositionLog));
            cfg.CreateMap<Position, PositionDto>();
            cfg.CreateMap<Queue<Position>, Queue<PositionDto>>();
        });

        configuration.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
        var mapper = configuration.CreateMapper();

        var target1 = new Target() {Id = 0};
        target1.Log = new Queue<int>();
        target1.Log.Enqueue(1);
        target1.Log.Enqueue(2);
        target1.Log.Enqueue(3);

        target1.PositionLog = new Queue<Position>();
        var p1 = new Position();
        var p2 = new Position();
        target1.PositionLog.Enqueue(p1);
        target1.PositionLog.Enqueue(p2);

        var targetDto = mapper.Map<TargetDto>(target1);

    }
}
```

In case we have `PositionLog` properties of type `List<Position>` and `List<PositionDto>` mapping works correctly. If we change type of `PositionLog` property in class `TargetDto` to be of type `Queue<Position>` then it works as well.

I use AutoMapper of version 8.1.1 and .NET Core 2.2

Answer (score 0):

AM doesn't special case `Queue<T>`, `List<T>` is the default collection type. But you can use `ICollection<PositionDto>`. And then you need just

```
    cfg.CreateMap<Target, TargetDto>();
    cfg.CreateMap<Position, PositionDto>();
```